# Count the digits

Tags: c++

Here's the question:

Take an integer n (n >= 0) and a digit d (0 <= d <= 9) as an integer. Square all numbers k (0 <= k <= n) between 0 and n. Count the numbers of digits d used in the writing of all the k**2. Call nb_dig (or nbDig or ...) the function taking n and d as parameters and returning this count.

But the output is one less than expected. Can anyone tell what am I missing:

Expected: equal to 4700

Actual: 4699

```
class CountDig
{
  public:
  static int nbDig(int n, int d)
  {
    if(n==0 && d==0)
      return 0; 
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<=n;i++)
    {
      int p=i*i;
      while(p)
      {
        int l;
        l=p%10;
        if(l==d)
          c++;
        p=p/10;
      }
    }

    return c;
  }
};
```

Comment: And what about `n` and `d`, their values?

Comment: `i<=n` will lead to access `a[i]` out of bounds.

Comment: @FilipKočica this is just the function, which is being called from the driver program!

Comment: Ofc but you have to pass some values to that function...

Comment: @FilipKočica there are three test cases,(5750,0) , (11011,2), (12224,8)

Comment: @yaoshinga  There is no need to declare an array. Moreover the declaration of the array in the function is not C++ compliant.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can you find which count am I missing? It always displays one less than the expected

Comment: Than add 1 if its always.

Comment: @yaoshinga As  user0042 pointed out your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @FilipKočica In that case the other test case returns value one more than expected!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just edited the code!

Comment: So dont type `always` if its not always and stop yelling.

Answer (score 2):

You dont count the first zero (0*0), because the loop condition is p (while(p)).

So add a condition to add one to c, if p is zero and d is zero

```
class CountDig
{
public: static int nbDig(int n, int d)
{
    int c=0;
    if (d==0)
         c=1; // start from 1, when counting 0
   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
      int p=i*i;
      while(p)
     {
        int l;
        l=p%10;
         if(l==d)
            c++;
        p=p/10;
     }

  }
return c;
}
};
```

Comment: the if condition: if(n==0 && d==0) is specifically for that one.

Comment: that special case doesn't solve the problem. it's not where n and d are zero that you need to worry about. It's where i is zero in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` and `d` are both zero, then the count of `0` should be 1.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the case when we need d=0 and n!=0. In answer you are running the loop from 1 onwards so you are missing the starting zero.
In the end you only have to include one line.

```cpp
if (d==0) 
    return count+1;
else
    return count;
```